# Query on Hystrix Command

Tags: java, hystrix

I have query on Hystrix command

I am accesing the below resource with four different operation

1) http://api.alert.com/send

2) http://api.alert.com/update

3) http://api.alert.com/retrieve

4) http://api/alert.com/call

My question is:
do we need to create 4 Hystrix commands to access the below resource

one Hystrix command itself enough to handle the four operations ?

suggest the best solution for this.

Comment: It depends on whether you want to configure each call separately with different configurations, timeouts or not

Comment: but each request and response type is different right. how's it possible to have single hystrix command for 4 resources even if i use same configuration. can you provide some example to understand single hystrix command for 4 different resource ?